# Package Eclipse Repository During Release

Tags: maven, tycho

I managed to create plug-ins to force Tycho to release almost all packaging types except for `eclipse-repository`.

The problem is that during the `release:perform` at some point a `deploy` is called, visible in the log as:

```
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:perform (default-cli) @ org.acme.project.rxp-build ---
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn [snip]"
[INFO] Working directory: workspace\org.acme.project.rxp-build\target
[INFO] Invoking perform goals in directory workspace\org.acme.project.rxp-build\target\checkout
[INFO] Executing goals 'deploy'...
```

Now this `deploy` does not work in Tycho (and in fact, should not work) as the standard `deploy`, that's what makes the release fail. I was wondering if there is any way to change the goals called by the release plug-in to add something to call the normal `deploy`.

The goal can not be changed by the `completionGoals` nor the `preparationGoals` nor the `goals` like this (at least not only for the `eclipse-repository`, where I need the changes):

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <completionGoals>other goals</completionGoals>
      <preparationGoals>other goals</preparationGoals>
      <goals>other goals</goals>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

So how can I change the goal called by the release process to have the default behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by *normal* deploy? See http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#goals.

Comment: @AleksandrM When I call `mvn deploy` one thing happens, when `release:perform` calls it, another thing happens. I had hoped to change it to the first kind of `deploy`.

Comment: And how is *normal* deploy differs from release plugin deploy?

Comment: @AleksandrM It works. More specific, it builds the `eclipse-repository` in its `package` phase. The release deploy doesn't.